# How do you post data from JS to Flask, manipulate the data then send it back to JS?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I'm posting data from my HTML to Flask with:

```
$.ajax({
            let name = 'ari_victor'
            url: '/send_data',
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({name}),
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
```

It arrives on the Backend

```
@app.route('/send_data', methods=['POST'])
def send_data():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json()
        name = data['name'].replace('_', ' ').title()
```

Now how do I send it back? to the HTML/JS?

```
        return name # ?
```

Edit: I'm doing an ajax post so I dont have to refresh the page, and I'd like to not refresh the page when getting the data back if possible. I know how to easily do this with a form and rendering a new template but I'd like to have a go at developing a single page application

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In flask view you have to define some kind of response `return 'Hello World'` for instance, or preferably json response `jsonify(msg=success)`. Then you have to "catch" the response from ajax.
It is done here in your ajax statement:

```
success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
```

`response` object contains all response information, just printing here but you can provide callback of your own and do whatever you like :)